# Connecting an existing system to a mixer

Tags: mixer, cable, xlr, connector

First off, I realise that none of this system is ideal. When the strange Covid conditions are over, we will be sorting it out properly: this is very much a "for now" solution.

My church has an existing sound system, with three wireless microphones, leading into a T-loop system and ultimately a Denon DN-300R recorder. The recorder's outputs are the only ones we can easily access. We have also purchased some additional microphones (the existing ones are really good only for speech, not for the organ/choir music we have) and the Behringer Xenyx X2222USB mixer. (Ultimately, all this audio ends up in our live-stream: we have no speakers in the building.)

My question is how to get the audio signal from the existing system into the mixer. The recorder's outputs are (a) a phones jack, (b) an RCA pair, (c) an XLR pair. (The audio recorder only receives mono inputs, so we only need one channel.)

The mixer can have three types of input: mic-level XLR; line-level jack (balanced or unbalanced); line-level RCA.

What is the best way of getting the audio from the existing system into the mixer?

I'm not remotely an expert, but the system I've come up with is getting an female XLR to male balanced TRS jack cable to go from the recorder's output to one of the line-level inputs. But is there a better way?

Comment: What do you want the mixer to do? There doesn’t seem to be a purpose for having it at the end of the signal chain.

Comment: Mix other sources (four more microphone inputs, potentially also from a computer in the future) in, then output via the USB audio interface.

Comment: You should plug all of the microphones into the mixer first and then distribute it from there

Comment: @Timinycricket Yes, of course we should. For now, though, we can't. It's not possible without rewiring that those of us present are not competent to do. What should we do in the meantime?

Comment: I’m sure if you reach out to another church in the area they will have a tech. person that would be happy to help set that up for you

Comment: @Timinycricket Indeed – or we could pay our normal engineer – but they're currently not allowed to come here because of the restrictions now in place.

Comment: then you should go ahead and do it the way you have proposed.

Comment: @Timinycricket Cool, many thanks for your help.